# C# quiz code not working properly

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am making a quiz which was working up to a point but after trying to increase its complexity it doesn't work completely as it should. All that happens at the moment is that the possible answers in my Access database table are binded to each radio button on my C# form.

This part is OK, however, it is no longer telling me after clicking on my button whether or not the answer I have selected is correct or not. I am using a label at the moment to tell the user if the answer is correct.

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class quizQuestions : Form
    {
        public quizQuestions()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //int questionNumber;
        //String correctAnswer;
        private void WindowsAnalysisQuiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare connection string using windows security
            string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\quizQuestions.accdb";

            //declare Connection, command and other related objects
            OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
            OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

            //try
            //{
            //open connection
            conGet.Open();
            String correctAnswer;

            cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

            cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM quizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()"; // select all columns in all rows

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            label1.Text = reader["Question"].ToString();
            radioButton1.Text = reader["Answer 1"].ToString(); 
            radioButton2.Text = reader["Answer 2"].ToString();
            radioButton3.Text = reader["Answer 3"].ToString();
            radioButton4.Text = reader["Answer 4"].ToString();
            correctAnswer = reader["Correct Answer"].ToString();
            //questionNumber = 1;

            conGet.Close();

        }

        private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\quizQuestions.accdb";

            //declare Connection, command and other related objects
            OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
            OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

            //try
            {
                //open connection
                conGet.Open();

                cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

                //cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM quizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()"; // select all columns in all rows

                OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                String chosenAnswer = "";
                int chosenCorrectly = 0;
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 1"].ToString();
                }
                else if (radioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 2"].ToString();
                }
                else if (radioButton3.Checked)
                {
                    chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 3"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 4"].ToString();
                }

                if (chosenAnswer == reader["Correct Answer"].ToString())
                {
                    //chosenCorrectly++;
                    label2.Text = "You have got this answer correct";
                    //label2.Text = "You have got " + chosenCorrectly + " answers correct";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("That is not the correct answer");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So to summarise, the possible answers are loaded into the form OK, but when I press the button on the form to determine if the correct answer has been chosen, nothing at all happens.

Comment: your Sql command has no query, you've commented it out..

Comment: Is the event handler being ran? Have you tried debug it?

Comment: Is it the same question you are referring to for checking the answer ? I see a order by rnd() in both places ! ! If you already have the correct answer in the string why are you again hitting the database to check it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the `btnNextQuestion_Click` anywhere in your code, and you are not giving a `cmdGet.CommandText` in your `btnNextQuestion_Click` function. You may have to be more specific on what doesnt happen. Have you debugged it?

Comment: Control events are normally bound in the code that the form designer creates, so you won't see it in the regular code.

Answer (score 0):

If truly "nothing" happens, then you should check that the click event of the button is still bound to the event handler.

You have commented out the line where you set the `CommandText` for the query, so you are trying to execute the command with not query set, which should give you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something terribly wrong in what you have got there. You are assigning the answers to the Text property and already have the correct answer in a string.

Just check the same against the checked `RadioButton` Text and you would know.
Also its difficult to guess what you are querying in the `btnNextQuestion_Click` event  and i have my reservations as its actually the same question which is currently displayed and with an answer chosen by the user.